# Is "Circular" list a kind of "linear list"?

Tags: algorithm, circular-list

I'm not sure what kind of "list", could be considered as "linear list".

For example, if the concept "linear" means we have one and only one rule to say what is the "next" element: then "Circular list", should also be "linear list"?

If yes, then "general lists", although they could have high dimensional structure, but as long as we give the rule of how to find "next" element, could it be considered as "linear list"?

Comment: Going on a limb here. Circular lists and "regular" lists are all linearly traversable. Some data structures (e.g., trees) are not linearly traversable. Not sure if there is a thing as a non-linaer list.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_list_operations

Comment: I never heard of "linear list" (even wiki doesn't have a definition), only "linear linked list". More or less a terminology issue. When you say something is linear, which means its graph can be represented like a straight line. So I guess it's why "circular list" doesn't have linear in its name

Comment: @HoàngLong But when you think / model the "circular list" as an infinite long repeating sequence, it still can be represented by a straight line...infinite long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circular lists are linear data structures. However, it is not sufficient to give a rule for finding next element: in order for the structure to be linear, a single element must not be the next element to more than one element.

For example, the structure below is *not* linear:

[image: Non-linear list]

Although each node has at most one successor, node "C" is a successor to two other nodes - "B" and "F". The structure is, therefore, cannot be considered linear.

A list of linear data structures can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Linear_data_structures).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what context you are coming from with this question, but my understanding of "circular list" in general computer data structure terminology is a list where the last element points back to the first element, so that the list could be traversed infinitely. This has usefulness in certain applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right that , **linearly linked** means that you have a specific method for reaching to a **unique next** node

Because of a little difference in implementation of **circular lists** ,that is,

**None of the pointers points to a NULL** and becoz of it's infinite nature
[image]

there tends to be a confusion ...

**but**
**Circular Linked List** is generally called as a **linear Linked List** only

**Note that**

a **tree** is called a non linear datatype because **one node's** next could be more than one node so **not a unique next node** hence ** tree is example of non linear**